# How non static method working statically on localhost

Tags: php, oop

I made a class and in that class made a public method. now am calling that method as static method and its working fine. How?

if I upload this code on PHP fiddle its giving error which I was expecting. But why it's not giving error on localhost

```
 class A
    {
        public function b()
        {
            echo "i am b";
        }
    }
    print_r(A::b());
```

Comment: What version of PHP do you use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Statical call of a non-statical method [is deprecated](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration56.deprecated.php) since 5.6 version of PHP. It means if you call a non-statical method like statical you get an error of E_DEPRECATED level.
If you don't see this error you should reconfigure [error reporting](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) and enable [display errors](https://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.display-errors).
For example:

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```